# Am I correctly confused by the git repository structure in the Go workspace in the examples on "How to Write Go Code"?

Tags: go

I have 2 points of confusion about the [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) article. They may be mistakes in the article, or I may just be missing the point. In describing the structure of the typical workspace, the article says

> The src subdirectory typically contains multiple version control repositories (such as for Git or Mercurial) that track the development of one or more source packages.

The first example workspace in the article matches this description, with 2 folders representing repositories (`github.com/golang/example/` and `golang.org/x/image/`), each of which has a .git directory immediately below it.

Later, the article says:

> If you're using a source control system, now would be a good time to initialize a repository, add the files, and commit your first change. Again, this step is optional: you do not need to use source control to write Go code.

Then the article shows example code running `git init` in the `src/github.com/user/hello/` directory. This is point of confusion #1. Since `github.com/user` is the repository and `hello` is the package, it seems like the `git init` should be done at the level of `github.com/user`.

Point of confusion #2 comes near the end of the article, when it says:

> After issuing the above go get command, the workspace directory tree should now look like this:

It then shows another example repository, which has a `.git` directory under the `github.com/golang/example/` directory, but none under the `github.com/user/` directory, either right below it or in the `hello` package where it was initialized earlier.

My questions are:

1. Should the repository have been initialized in the `hello` directory or one level up?
2. Should the final repository show a `.git` directory?

Comment: `github.com/user` is not a repository URI (it's your user account root, essentially), the repo is the next path down. GitHub's URI convention is `github.com/{user-or-organization-name}/{repo-name}`.

Answer (score 2):

> Since `github.com/user` is the repository and `hello` is the package, it seems like the `git init` should be done at the level of `github.com/user`.

No it isn't. `github.com/user` is a github user. Users have repositories, such as `github.com/user/hello`. A repository can hold one or more go packages, including one which may be at the top level of the repository, and have the same name as the repository.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. In this case, `hello` is both a "repository" and a "package". As an aside, I still think there should be a `.git` directory shown in the final workspace hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to does not show directory trees accurately - they combine directory names together which means directories of the same depth don't necessarily appear to have the same depth.

This is not the documentation being *wrong* - it's fairly common to flatten directory trees to avoid wasting screen-space (especially in Java projects where you'll have many directories all containing only a single subdirectory due to Java's file/package naming convention enforced by their compiler).

The tree diagram after "After issuing the above go get command, the workspace directory tree should now look like this:" should really look like this:

```
bin/
    hello                                   # command executable
src/
    github.com/
        golang/
            example/
                .git/                       # 
                hello/
                    hello.go                # 
                stringutil/                 #
                    reverse.go              # 
                    reverse_test.go         # 
        user/
            hello/                          # "github.com/user/hello" package repo root
                hello.go                    # 
            stringutil/                     # "stringutil" package source root, but not a repo
                reverse.go                  # 
                reverse_test.go             # test source
```

Note that `github.com/user` is described as a "base path" and not as a repository root or package path, but `github.com/user/hello` *is* described as a package root.

Comment: I don't think I was confused by the flattened directories. I was confused by the git path convention of `github.com/{user-or-organization-name}/{repo-name}` in your comment above.

Comment: It probably didn't help that the article uses the word "package" when they should probably say "repository", e.g. 
"Again, the first step is to choose a package path (we'll use github.com/user/stringutil) and create the package directory."

Comment: Also, I still think the directory structure above should have a .git directory somewhere  below `user/`.

Comment: @learnJ12 you can have multiple packages in the same repository.

Comment: yes but in this case `stringutil` is the directory just below `user` so shouldn't it be considered the repository and not the package?

Comment: @learnJ12 They are using "package" for a reason, and if they were to use "repository" instead *that* would be a mistake. Note that using repositories to hold your package(s) is optional, your package does *not* have to live in a folder that's associated to some vcs repo. Packages are part of the language spec, required by the compiler and essential for your code to work. The use of repositories on the other hand is but a convention, nothing will break if you don't utilize them.

Comment: @mkopriva The "Overview" section of the article says: "A workspace contains many version control repositories. Each repository contains one or more packages." And in this case the "hello" package is in the path `src/github.com/user/hello`. So you are saying that `hello` is a package not living in a repository, `github.com/user` is here used as a namespace with no associated repository, and the convention specified in the Overview is in this case not used?

Comment: @learnJ12 what I meant to say is that you can have a package live *anywhere* in the gopath's src directory, for example in `$GOPATH/src/hello` and you'll be able to import it using the path relative from `src`, i.e. `import "hello"`, or you can have your package in `$GOPATH/src/iam/not/github/hello` and then you can import it with `import "iam/not/github/hello"`. What's important is that your package lives somewhere in `$GOPATH/src/` it can be a repo but it doesn't have to be, it can containt `.git` but it doesn't have to.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you for the clarification. I think that I'm getting it, but I do think it's a bit confusing in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> Should the repository have been initialized in the hello directory or one level up?

assuming `hello` directory is the root of your project, and that you are using a Version Control System, yes.

In the blog post, at https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Command, yes, this directory is the root of the hello program/project, belonging to the namespace `github.com/user/`. As a consequence, and because this demo uses a VCS, currently `git`, yes it contains a `.git` directory.

> Should the final repository show a .git directory?

If this **is** a **repository** then yes, it contains a `.git`, or alike, directory to store metadatas of the VCS.

Although, having a repository, ie a directory managed by a VCS, is not mandatory to run go programs.

It is a requirement you have when you want to navigate over history, and / or save multiple state of a program, and / or write and share your code with other people.

In enterprise environment it is required (99.999999%, there must be some fools, we are only humans).